# SpringBoot - extending configuration classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends SpringSecurityConfiguration {
}
```

..

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    jsr250Enabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true,
    proxyTargetClass = true
)
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public SpringSecurityConfiguration() {
    }
..
}
```

but when I deploy I have this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used on eSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e8ee1d6f@18dbc2eb, so it cannot be used on
```

Comment: Both classes will be instantiated due to the `@Configuration` which isn't possible. So either make `SpringSecurityConfiguration` `abstract` or remove `@Configuration` or find a different way of extending the configuration. You probably are better of by implementing `WebSecurityConfigurer` if you want to extend the configuration.